# Logging in to Stack Overflow with private key

Tags: discussion, login, security, authentication

Most of the time you access Linux machines you'll use SSH with a private key. You add your public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and done, you can login using your private key and passphrase.

To serve HTTPS traffic, you use your private key to create a certificate signing request. You submit the request to a certificate authority and receive a certificate in return.  The certificate is basically a stamp of approval on your private key.

Today I noticed that the certificate authority I use (http://startssl.com/) also acts as an OpenID provider.  If I log on to Stack Overflow using `https://yourname.startssl.com`, I can log on using just my private key, just like an SSH server.

It seems really easy to use. One time import of the certificate, and no need to remember the password unless you reinstall the machine.

Is this way of logging on a good idea?

Comment: I was about to flag as off-topic.. then two paragraphs later...

Comment: Excuse me, I can't follow you. OpenID allows you to authenticate *at another service* which then tells SE "yup, that's the one". So basically it doesn't matter for SE as long as the other service tells it that everything is ok. So if it is a good idea or not, depends on the authentication that *other* service uses...or did I miss something?

Comment: If it works it works, I'm pretty sure it's not a hack or anything. Stack Exchange just needs OpenID it doesn't care how it works behind the scenes. :)

Comment: See also: [Can't I just login to openid.SE.com using my browser's certificate mechanism instead of it's password keyring?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286285) Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is a good idea. As long as your browser is secure there is no problem. This is exactly what OpenID was meant to be: a way for *you* to choose your security level.

I have thought about setting up my own OpenID provider which could log me in automatically for example if I'm on my home computer. Other means of authorization may be to require a fingerprint, two different passwords or perhaps sending out an SMS code which you must provide as proof that you have the phone associated with the account. All this is possible without Stack Exchange intervention and I think it opens up for great freedom once OpenID is in more widespread use!