# Can't I just log in with openID.SE.com using my browser's certificate mechanism instead of its password keyring?

Tags: feature-request, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I'm using OpenID provided by Stack Exchange to authenticate to different services across the web.

This reduces the number of necessary logins to one per session for all those sites that provide OpenID. Still, I have to enter login and password for OpenExchange.

**Can't I just** generate a key pair and provide Stack Exchange with the public key, while my browser keeps the private key to **sign in using its certificate mechanism instead of its password keyring**?

Comment: TLS client certs have [practical problems](https://pineight.com/mw/index.php?title=User:Tepples/Cookie_alternatives#TLS_client_authentication).

Comment: Keep in mind many users have never heard of client certificates. Relatively few people would use this feature.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I personally would. I do agree it makes little sense to implement this on a non-tech site but it could be a good idea for a site such as Stack Exchange.